# Holoviews Table does not visually preserves index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, holoviews, pyviz

Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh','matplotlib','plotly')

mydf = pd.DataFrame({
                     'x':np.arange(5),
                     'y':-np.arange(5),
                     'z':2+3*np.arange(5)
                    }
                   )
statdf = pd.DataFrame({'min':mydf.min(),
                       'max':mydf.max(),
                       'mean':mydf.mean()}).T
statdf
```

and in the next cell:

```py
hv.Table(statdf)
```

Then you will get something like this:
[image: illustration of the issue]

Any help or clarification would be more that welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: try `hv.Table(statdf.reset_index())`

Comment: Thank you @Kenan. This surely injects the my index as a column and it is my current workaround - but I was mostly interested in seeing it in the row index section - where it simply belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) You could set the index as your key dimension:**

```
hv.Table(statdf, kdims=['index'])
```

**When using the bokeh backend this will still give you the extra hv.Table() index.** But this could also be an advantage, when you are sorting and want your dataframe back in the original order.
However, when you have the matplotlib or plotly backend `hv.extension('plotly')` this solution will give you a dataframe with index.


**2) Another option is to use a panel dataframe widget instead.**
That will show the dataframe with the original index and still allows sorting etc.:

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension()

pn.widgets.DataFrame(statdf)
```

More info on pn.widgets.DataFrame():
https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/DataFrame.html#widgets-gallery-dataframe


**Resulting dataframe using the panel widget:**

[image: dataframe using panel widget]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`hv.Table(statdf.reset_index())`

I don't think you can update the index column in `holoviews`